# CLI/C++ Virtual EventHandler

Tags: event-handling, c++-cli, virtual

I have a class A which implements a interface I.

In interface I is the declaration:

```
virtual event System::EventHandler ^eh;
```

In header file of A I implement this by a similare declaration:

```
virtual event System::EventHandler ^eh;
```

in the cpp file of A I want to assign the delegate of the event  to anotheter variable:

```
EventHandler ^eh2 = eh;
```

This gives error

> Error 285 error C3918: usage requires 'eh' to be a data

I also try

```
EventHandler^ eh2 = gcnew System::EventHandler(eh);
```

This gives error:

> Error 285 error C3924: error in argument #1 of delegate constructor
>   call 'System::EventHandler':

Comment: Can you post your whole interface and implementing class declaration, and the whole function where you get the compile error? Other than that, have you read this? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w901cc8a%28v=VS.100%29.aspx

Comment: What happens when you remove virtual from the interface's definition of your event? Only the implementing class should define the event as virtual, not the interface itself.

Comment: @Roger: Slightly unrelated, but an interface does not define, it just declares

Comment: If I remove virtual I get a compilation error. In CLI/Cpp I must use the virtual keyword if I want to overload. If I try to create a new member in the A class which is not virtual, then the code will compile. So there is something with the virtual attribute which makes the compile error. For some reason the compiler cannot find the real type of the passed parameter. Or the compiler cannot reassure that there always will be passed a parameter.

Comment: I haved read the link which dario_ramos refer to, but I could not relate it to my problem 100%, but it gave me a feeling of whats wrong, that the compiler have problems resolving the type of the passed parameter, or that the compiler cannot be sure that there will always be a parameter to assign.

Answer (score 4):

The *event* keyword explicitly forbids accessing an event like this.  The only valid operations are adding a handler (+= operator), removing one (-= operator) and raising the event.  If you want access to the underlying delegate object then you have to provide the add and remove accessors to wrap the delegate object instead of using the default ones that the compiler generates.  Like this:

```
public interface class IFoo {
    event EventHandler^ eh;
};

ref class Bar : IFoo {
private:
    EventHandler^ dlg;
public:
    event EventHandler^ eh {
        virtual void add(EventHandler^ handler) { dlg += handler; }
        virtual void remove(EventHandler^ handler) { dlg -= handler; }
    };
public:
    void test() {
        EventHandler^ copy = dlg;
        // etc.., fire for example
        copy(this, EventArgs::Empty);
    }
};
```

Do consider if this is really what you want to do, it is fairly unlikely to be correct.

Comment: I dont think this is the answer to the problem. My example will compile if <eh> is not virtual